# How to close all tabs except the active one on demand with content script in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs, sendmessage

I'm trying to close all tabs except the active one. I found the extension in the store: [Close All Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/close-all-tabs/jcokdfogijmigonkhckmhldgofjmfdak). I simplified it leaving the function I needed.

manifest.json:

```
{
   "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/128.png",
      "default_title": "Close All Tabs"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Close All Tabs",
   "version": "1.1.1"
}
```

background.js:

```
const closeAllTabs = function(thisTab) {
    let querying = chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
        for (let tab of tabs) {
            console.log(tab.id);
            console.log(thisTab.id);
            if (tab.id !== thisTab.id) chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
        }
    // result with 2 tab:
    // 50035
    // 50035
    // 50041
    // 50035
    });
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(thisTab) {
    closeAllTabs(thisTab);
});
```

The extension works if you click on the icon, then all tabs except the active one will close. I changed this by adding a content script that sends a message instead of a click.

manifest.json:

```
{
   "background": {
      "persistent": true,
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },
   "permissions": ["background","tabs","<all_urls>","activeTab"],  
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
    ],
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Close All Tabs",
   "version": "1.1.1"
}
```

background.js:

```
const closeAllTabs = function(thisTab) {
    let querying = chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
        for (let tab of tabs) {
            console.log(tab.id);
            console.log(thisTab.id);
            if (tab.id !== thisTab.id) chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
        }
    // result with 2 tab:
    // 50035
    // undefined
    // 50041
    // undefined
    });
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(thisTab) {
    closeAllTabs(thisTab);
});
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({});
```

But it doesn't work(all pages close). Why when I click on the extension icon everything works. And when I send a message and run the function, thisTab.id cannot be determined (underfined)?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of [onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) is the message that you sent. The tab is inside the second parameter:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {
  closeAllTabs(sender.tab);
});
```